# **UNSOLVED** Find an integer $\geqslant2$ that is build up out of only $1$'s and $0$'s in base $1,\;\ldots,\;10$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, contest-math

This riddle bothers me for a few weeks now and I'm starting to worry that I need some $p$-adic Number theory to solve this. I solve most of the riddles in a day, but this one is just annoying to me. I was thinking of taking the number $10!$. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**  I'm looking for a number that is written as only a series of $1$'s and $0$'s which represent the number $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n*p^n$ with $a_n\in\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ where $a_n$ is either $1$ or $0$.

**Edit 2** Probably this is a not so well known problem, but people are working on it with no solution yet found for this case. They let a program search for such numbers and there were no matches so far. There is a solution in base $1,\;\ldots,\;5$, namely $$82000 = 10100000001010000\ (2) = 11011111001\ (3) = 110001100\ (4) = 10111000\ (5).$$
This number fails in the original problem for $82000=1431344\ (6)$.

Originally checked to $2^{65520}$ (or about $3*10^{19723}$) on Nov 07 2008.

Conjectured to be complete. a(4), if it exists, it is greater than $10^{15}$. Apr 06 2012.

In 2016, a Mathematician stated that it is plausible that there are no more such terms, but it is not proven.

See for yourself: https://oeis.org/A146025.

Comment: As another way of putting it, you are looking for an integer $≥2$ which can be written as a sum of distinct powers of $2$, and distinct powers of $3$, up to distinct powers of $10$.

Comment: There is no answer for this if you specify that there must be atleast one $1$ and one $0$ because $0$  does not appear in base 1 , if by chance its not a necessity , then a solution may exist

Comment: @lulu that's correct. I'm looking for a number that is written as only a series of 1's and 0's which represent the $number=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n*p^n$ with $a_n\in\mathbb{F}_n$.

Comment: @lulu I do mean base 1,...,10. Doesn't matter because in base 1, every number is written out of solely 1's. And I meant 10 faculty, not 10, I know 10 doesn't work. Maybe 10*9*8*...*2 does the job.

Comment: I don't see a terribly good way to attack it systematically.  I would do a search by listing all the $1,0$-integers in bases $4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ (the missing ones are implied by these)  and look for intersections.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen 10, 11 and 101 are not only 1's in 0's in every base 1,...,10. You should look up what a base means. I appreciate you taking time to think about it.

Comment: This is the same problem as this right? http://andybohn.com/82000/ if so, we don't know the number you are looking for. 82,000 works for bases 1-5, but we don't know of a number that works in bases 1-6.

Comment: Ahh, you want it to work in every base. Sorry. I knew I was missing something :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Doesn't matter, glad you want to help! It is indeed the same difficult problem, but then with more bases.

Comment: [OEIS reports that it is unknown whether the sequence continues](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C3%2C4%2C82000&language=english&go=Search). The latest update there is from 2016. Some very bright people contribute to OEIS, so it is a safe bet that we can't find an answer by random poking. Whoever gave you this puzzle was a bit naughty :-)

Comment: Following through the links given by Enricoborba, one learns that even the relaxed problem of finding a number that works for bases 1-6 which should by all rights be much easier than the problem of finding a number that works for bases 1-10 is currently beyond our collective ability to do and is research level mathematics.  No solution for the problem of finding the smallest (*or even any*) number for bases 1-6 exists with less than 10000 digits in base ten (*by brute force checking*).

Comment: [Another OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A146025) claims that the next number after $82000$ that works in bases $3,4,5$ is larger than $2^{65520}$. Assuming one exists, that is unknown! I think we will need a bit more than some $p$-adic tricks to settle this. Yes, intriguing as this may be you can call foul on whoever assigned the problem :-)

Comment: That being said... I am unsure of the protocol on dealing with unanswerable questions.  Perhaps @JyrkiLahtonen can enlighten us on the topic.  Close for reason that it can't be answered given current methods?  Answer with an "unanswerable" and explanation as to what progress has been done on the problem so far?  Or leave open indefinitely with no answer...

Comment: I found it on a list of riddles to test non-mathematician co-workers if their mathematics skills were on point. I thought, as a 2nd year bachelor mathematics, that I could solve em all. This was the last one, soo yeah, pretty sadistic of them :-)) Thanks for your research! At least a little releaf that it was out of my reach.

Comment: @JMoravitz Being a diamond bearer I probably should know but I don't. If it were a well-known open problem, yes we would close. I'm not sure this is that well known. For my generation a Numberphile appearance doesn¨t make it "well-known". So, frankly, I don't know if we have a policy. I guess we will gradually form one. The problem is not very pressing, you know. I mean, we don¨t have too many threads like this to absolutely need a policy :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some heuristic argument (too long for a comment):

Suppose we have an $n$-digit number $m$ in base 10 that can be represented by 0s and 1s.  There are $2^{n-1}$ such $m$s.  Written in a different basis $B$, that number has approximately $n / \log B$ digits where $\log$ denotes the logarithm to base 10.

Assuming that the digits of $m$ in other bases are independent, the probability that a digit in base $B$ happens to be in $\{0,1\}$ is $2/B$.  Thus, the probability that the representation is again all 0s and 1s in base $B$ is$$\left(\frac2B\right)^{n/\log B}$$

As the condition shall hold for more than one basis, we arrive at a probability of
$$\prod_{4\leqslant B \leqslant 9} \left(\frac2B\right)^{n/\log B}$$
that $m$ meets the condition in all bases.  Notice that the condition is met trivially for $B=2$, and when the condition is met for $B=9$, then it's also met for $B=3$.

The
$\def\mod{\operatorname{mod}}$
conditions for $B=8$ and $B=4$ are not independent, though, because they are linked by the binary representation: If we expand the octal digits pair-wise in binary, $m$ has the following representation in groups of 6 bits: $$\cdots00b_i\,00b_j\cdots$$
Thus matching $B=4$ and $B=8$ means $b_i=0$ where $i=3\mod 6$. Only $b_j$ can be chosen (where $j=0\mod 6$).  Which means we can replace the two bases 4 and 8 by $B=2^6=64$.  Hence a corrected probability for $m$ to match is
$$\prod_{B\in\{5, 6, 7, 9, 64\}} \left(\frac2B\right)^{n/\log B}$$
and the expected number of finds amongst the $n$-decimal digit numbers is
$$E_n=2^{n-1}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\prod_{B\in\{5, 6, 7, 9, 64\}} \left(\frac2B\right)^{n/\log B}
=\left( 0.5\!\!\!\!\!\!\prod_{B\in\{5, 6, 7, 9, 64\}} \left(\frac2B\right)^{1/\log B} \right)^n =:a^n
$$
This gives a value of
$$ a \approx 0.000227 $$
with the following contributions of the $B$s:

```
  B |   2/B    | 1/log B  | (2/B)^(1/log B)
 ---+----------+----------+----------------
  5 | 0.400000 | 1.430677 | 0.269573
  6 | 0.333333 | 1.285097 | 0.243698
  7 | 0.285714 | 1.183295 | 0.227095
  9 | 0.222222 | 1.047952 | 0.206759
 64 | 0.031250 | 0.553655 | 0.146780
```

Under the assumption that the $E_n$s are independent, the expected value of solutions with $n_0$ digits or more is
$$
\sum_ {n\geqslant n_0}E_n
=\sum_{n\geqslant n_0}a^n
= a^{n_0} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n
= a^{n_0} \frac1{1-a} \approx a^{n_0}
$$
where the approximation assumes $|a|\ll 1$ which hols for our $a$.

According to [OEIS.A146025](https://oeis.org/A146025), there is no solution for our $B$s below $3\cdot 10^{19723}$ (except the trivial ones 0 and 1), and therefore we get an estimate using $n_0=19723$:
$$
E_{\geqslant 19723} \approx 0.000227^{19723}\approx 10^{-71870}
$$

**Conclusion:** If I had to bet whether there exists a solution to your problem, I wouldn't even bet a flower pot — except I wanted to get rid of that pot real quick.